# HOWTO award extra bounties?

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I'm feeling a bit inadequate because I've searched the FAQ and Meta and still cannot figure out *how* to award bounties to questions I have not posted. I have found multiple questions implying that this is possible, and advice such as "Simply go to the question, start a bounty, select the amount of rep you want to donate." But which button, icon or right-clickity incantation do I need to see that I currently am overlooking?

Comment: Which question are you trying to award? I think there is a minimum age it has to be before bounties can be awarded.

Comment: The option appears two days after the question has been asked and only when you have atleast 75 rep. Check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work for more details

Comment: I have >50K rep on SO. I have checked that meta-answer. Still unable to figure this out. As a concrete example I go to this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059200/inputting-a-whole-data-frame-as-independent-variables-in-a-logistic-regression ... where/what should I be seeing that I can activate/click/whatever to allow me to add a bounty (not that I want to for this question, but it is one that is over 24 hours old).

Comment: The Start a Bounty Link appears below the comments

Comment: The supposed answer to the supposed "duplicate" stated : "To start a bounty, click on the "start a bounty" link at the bottom of an eligible question." I _had_ looked at the "bottom of the question" which I took to mean the area that had the "edit" button, but I had not looked at the "below the comments"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option to start a bounty appears below the comments,  but it only appears after 2 days of the posting of the question. Below is a screenshot of the option available for the question you linked as an example.

[image]

Comment: Sigh. There it is. Must have breezed over it several hundred times. Thank you.